# how do i get www to non-www then into a web root subfolder using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?toolmegastore.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/megastore/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subdirectory/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?toolmegastore.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ megastore/index.php [L]
```

I need to get this to redirect to non-www some how please but can't figure it out.. thanks in advance

Comment: You need to be more precise in your question. There is an "edit" link below it, _use it_ to revise your question. We understand that you want to strip the "www." prefix from the request host name. But it is completely unclear what that "web root subfolder" refers to, how that comes into play. Your given code makes little sense so we cannot guess from that what you are actually looking for.